# A special inverse Galois problem

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-numbers

Suppose that $G$ is a transitive permutation group and suppose we know a construction of an isomorphism from the Galois group of a Galois number field to $G$. Does this information make it easier to solve the following more special inverse Galois problem:

Let $\tau$ be an involution of $G$ (i.e. $\tau^2$ is the identity), can we find complex Galois number field $K$ such that its Galois group is isomorphic to $G$ and such that this isomorphism identifies $\tau$ with the complex conjugation?

I was thinking in the lines of ... if I know that I can find an integral irreducible polynomial $f$ such that the splitting field of $f$ has a Galois group isomorphic to $G$ (from the fact that I know, constructively, that $G$ is Galois realizable) then maybe I can "magically" modify (aka. perturb the coefficients of) $f$ such that it remains irreducible, has complex roots, the Galois group remains isomorphic to $G$ and by some continuity argument we could "force" the complex conjugation to be $\tau$.

I'm too inexperienced in Galois inverse problems and maybe someone with more knowledge could give me some intuition.

Comment: Group elements of order $2$ are *not* usually called idempotents, but *involutions*.

Comment: Sorry. Indeed, I meant involutions here. I always make this error of switching these two. I just corrected the original post, thank you.

Comment: I am probably more ignorant about inverse Galois theory than you are, but how would the elements of $G$ keep their identity when you perturb the polynomial (and presumably then also modify $K$)? My instincts would also suggest that, instead of specifying a fixed involution in $G$, you specify a *conjugacy class of involutions*. IMHO this might make a better defined problem for the following reason. When we specifty a Galois number field $K$ it does not come with a *unique* embedding into $\Bbb{C}$.

Comment: (cont'd) The different embeddings differ by elements of the Galois group. And if $\tau$ is the complex conjugation of $K$ for one embedding, then $\sigma\tau\sigma^{-1}$ is the complex conjugation on the embedding $\sigma(K)$. I'm not sure, but I suspect that problem would somehow "behave better".

Comment: An interesting question, nevertheless. I'm not sure in which way this might be a *special case* of inverse Galois theory. It probably isn't easier. After all, you really only concentrate on groups of an even order. IIRC for groups of odd order the inverse Galois problem has been solved, because such groups are solvable by Feit&Thompson.

Comment: Dear Jyrki. Thanks for the comment! Indeed, you can also always switch to any involution within the same conjugacy class by an inner automorphism of $G$. Feel free to edit the original post if you feel this formulation of the problem is "better" :)

Answer (score 5):

Although there are some contexts in which one can do something along these lines, there is no known mechanism to do this in general. In fact, there are many groups for which the inverse Galois problem is known, but the "more restrictive" version where you insist that complex conjugation lies in some chosen conjugacy class is open. For example, if $G = \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{F}_p)$, then there is a nice way to construct $G$-extensions by taking the $p$-torsion of a (general enough) elliptic curve $E/\mathbf{Q}$ and taking the corresponding number field. In this construction, complex conjugation is (for $p > 2$) always conjugate to

$$\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0  \\\ 0 & -1 \end{matrix} \right)$$

But if you now ask to find a $G$-extension in which complex conjugation is one of the other involutions (the identity or minus the identity) then this is an open problem (except for very small $p$).

Comment: Thank you and welcome to math.stackexchange. This is very interesting indeed. Do you happen to know a reference that claims that even for these realizable general linear groups the problem is open (for large $p$)?

Comment: It's clear from the (motivic) methods employed to construct these extensions that the sign condition is required. It's hard in general to give references to unproved statements but I assure you it is open. For a related but different question, the inverse Galois problem for $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{F}_p)$ is open, and the difficulty there is that the only possibility for complex conjugation is either the identity or minus the identity, and so motivic methods don't work here either.

Answer (score 0):

For permutation groups up to degree 19 this has been answered, with some exceptions which are not yet known, via computer algebra system (I believe Magma). If I ask that the involution is fixed-point-free I am looking for real signature 0 and this has a positive answer up to degree 16. The paper of J.Klüners and G.Malle: A Database for Field Extensions of the Rationals, LMS Jour. Comput. Math. 4 pp 182-196 (2001), explains this. The 2001 paper already has a link to their (exiting) database: http://galoisdb.math.upb.de/ , but back then I think they used KASH/KANT and listed this up to degree 11. Now they have up to degree 19 (still with many exceptions) and I think they use Magma to check (KASH implementation was included Magma back then but I think now Magma has some improvement maybe??). I contact Jürgen Klüners and he was kind enough to tell me these facts and give me all the exceptions up to degree 20 (degree 20 not yet online I think).